# how to use javascript varaiable in php

Tags: php

I'm developing an attendance management system. For that I need to populate the value of a textbox based on a listbox. For getting the selected value of the employee id without submitting a form i'm using javascript. Here is my code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function getvalue(){
var empid= document.getElementById("empid").value;
alert(empid);
<?php $abc = "<script>document.write(empid)</script>"?>   
}
<?php
$conn=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","attendance");
$result=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM add_emp WHERE Id ='".$abc."' ")or 
die(mysql_error());
$row = mysqli_fetch_array ($result);
?>
</script>
```

But in the output I'm seeing the line:

```
<script>document.write(empid)</script>
```

this string literal appears instead of the id.

Comment: I think you should learn about what is client side and server side? Where they will execute?

Comment: Learn about server & client side. That won't work. You need AJAX to perform such a task.

Comment: the php script its loaded before others thats why you fail . use ajax to pass variables